# If statements not working - select input for tp and sl

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is my code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 

https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © VSPuzzler

//@version=5
strategy("My script", overlay = true)

pt = 0
sl = 0

pip_PT = input.int(0,minval=0)
percent_PT = input.int(7, minval=0)

if (percent_PT != 0)
    pt = percent_PT * 100
else
    pt = pip_PT
    
pip_SL = input.int(0,minval=0)
percent_SL = input.int(7, minval=0)

if (percent_SL != 0)
    sl = percent_SL * 100
else
    sl = pip_SL

buy_signal = (((ta.rsi(close,7)[1]+ta.rsi(close,7)[2]+ta.rsi(close,7)[3])/3) > ta.rsi(close,7))
if bar_index < 100
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when = strategy.position_size <= 0)
strategy.exit("bracket", "buy", profit = pt, stop = sl)
```

When I run this script the if statements skip and the pt and sl variables remain at 0 and don't change with the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables can be declared with `=`, but when they are to be re-assigned later in the script you need to use `:=`. You will see this warning when you add your script to the chart. An example of what I mean here:

```
pt = 0 // we use equal sign here

if (percent_PT != 0)
    pt := percent_PT * 100 // we use assignment operator here
```

Cheers and have a great day